# Literary influences on Arundhati Roy, author of God of Small Things?

Tags: arundhati-roy, the-god-of-small-things

Is there any interview, essay etc. which mentions Arundhati Roy's literary influences? Or, is it possible to notice some influences just from reading *The God of Small Things*?

I ask because I love to read writers whose works influenced the work of my favourite authors.

Comment: Hello, I don't think your question is necessarily inappropriate, but you should take a look at the [how to ask a good question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and consider if it meets the requirements of being adequately researched. Just searching 'online for 'arundhati roy influences' quickly brings up several interviews where she is asked about this. Do those interviews allow you to answer your own question?